# Problem with using time check with if statments - BASH

Tags: bash

I am currently checking a .sh script just to do some basic things.

```
chmod +x catbash.sh

echo 'Hello, Please Enter your User Name'
echo
read VarUserName

currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
if [[ $currenttime > 11:59 ]] || [[ $currenttime < 12:00 ]]; 
    then echo 'Good Morning' $VarUserName'.'
        fi

if [[ $currenttime > 12:00 ]] || [[ $currenttime < 16:59 ]]; 
    then echo 'Good Afternoon' $VarUserName'.'
        fi

if [[ $currenttime > 17:00 ]] || [[ $currenttime < 19:59 ]]; 
    then echo 'Good Evening' $VarUserName'.'
        fi

if [[ $currenttime > 20:00 ]] || [[ $currenttime < 23:59 ]]; 
    then echo 'Good Night' $VarUserName'.'                                              
        fi
```

My issue is that i am trying to use the systems current time to be used in a if statement and depending on the time for a different output.

right now the script outputs all all of the "good...." echos and does not output a single echo depending on the time.

thank you for the help.

Comment: @el-teedee this is NOT a parsing issue ..  This is straight up logic  --  He needs `AND` instead of `OR` .. All if statement  are being executed and are *technically* true ..  So they all echo ..  Another way to make this *more correct* would be the use of `elif` so that no more than one technically *can* print out ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your conditions, all of them permit any given value, did you maybe want to use `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: Another stylistic improvement would be to use `elif` instead of always closing the previous `if` and starting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler if you would write it using the `elif` construction and start from the later times and work your way down.

```
chmod +x catbash.sh

currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
if [[ "$currenttime" > "19:59" ]]; then echo "Good Night ${USER}"
elif [[ "$currenttime" > "16:59" ]]; then echo "Good Evening ${USER}"
elif [[ "$currenttime" > "11:59" ]]; then echo "Good Afternoon ${USER}"
elif [[ "$currenttime" > "05:59" ]]; then echo "Good Morning ${USER}"
else echo "Good Night ${USER}"
```